# Need help with highlighting my grid graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have this highlighted gridgraph and I can't figure out how to get two highlight colors. I've identified the highlights by color, but I need to use blue for the `downleft` function. Any ideas?

[image: the graph]

```
crm[c_, r_, m_] := (c - 1) m + r
\[Kappa][n_, 2] := IntegerExponent[n, 2]

upright[i_, m_] := Module[{c, r, n, w, x, y, z},
w = crm[i, i, m];
If[i + i/2 > m, n = m, n = i + i/2];
x = Table[crm[i, r, m] <-> crm[i, r - 1, m], {r, i + 1, n}];
If[n != m, {y = crm[i, n, m];
 z = Table[crm[c, n, m] <-> crm[c - 1, n, m], {c, i + 1, n}];
 }, {y = w; z = w;
 }];
Flatten[{w, x, y, z}]
];

downleft[i_, m_] := Module[{c, r, n, w, x, y, z},
w = crm[i, i, m];
x = w; y = w; z = w;
n = (2 i - 1) - (3 (2 i - 1) + 1)/
  2^\[Kappa][(3 (2 i - 1) + 1), 2];
If[n != 0, {
 x = Table[
   crm[i, r, m] <-> crm[i, r + 1, m], {r, i - 1, i - n/2, -1}];
 y = crm[i, i - n/2, m];
 z = Table[
   crm[c, i - n/2, m] <-> crm[c + 1, i - n/2, m], {c, i - 1, 
    i - n/2, -1}];
 }];
Flatten[{w, x, y, z}]
];

myGraph[m_] := Module[{i(*,blue,red*)},
red = {}; blue = {};
For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
If[EvenQ[i],
  {red = Join[red, upright[i, m]];
   },
  {blue = Join[blue, downleft[i, m]]
   }];
];
GridGraph[{m, m}, VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Gray, 
GraphHighlight -> Join[blue, red]]
];

g=myGraph[16]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use HighlightGraph at the end of your function definition:

```
myGraph[m_] := Module[{i, blue, red}, red = {}; blue = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, 
   If[EvenQ[
      i], {red = Join[red, upright[i, m]];}, {blue = 
       Join[blue, downleft[i, m]]}];];
  HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{m, m}, VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Gray], {Style[blue, Blue], Style[red, Red]}]]
```

Comment: Your comments [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060163) would be very useful!  Or perhaps just a confirmation that what I am doing with `Graph` and `Options` at the moment is the best solution (plus any warning about cases in which it may not work as one would expect).